# Phusion Passenger not working with Apache while installing redmine

Tags: arch-linux, redmine

I am trying to install redmine (which is a ruby app ) in my arch system. But I am not able to fire up the app as it gives me the error for phusion passenger.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check with your environment.rb ? Is it there in /srv/http/config/ directory ?

Comment: there is no such path

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have something mis-configured in your Apache setup which is pointing to the path `/srv/http` -or- you don't have something configured which would've built out the path `/srv/http/config`.

I'd take a look at this [Howto/Guide from the ArchLinux wiki on setting up Redmine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redmine).

Comment: I am able to run the through webricks server

Comment: OK, that just shows that the webricks server included with Redmine works, which makes sense. Without more info we can't really help you any more than what I've suggested above. We need your Apache configs for example and to understand where the redmine install is.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am adding up the config files in my questions